# Stripe API - provide the reason for subscription cancellation

Tags: stripe-payments

In Stripe's UI there's the **REASON** column:

[image]

As per [Stripe's docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing), it's possible to cancel a subscription via API:

```js
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_J7rbZuZ0bLvmPVnuEKPFnIEC");

stripe.subscriptions.del('sub_49ty4767H20z6a');
```

Now, how can I pass the cancellation reason (provided by a user) to Stripe's API?

Comment: According to Stripe’s API refrerence this is currently not possible. Could maybe be in preparation of a future feature??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is possible to cancel subscriptions you cannot currently set a reason.

The reason displayed in the Stripe Dashboard is a (currently) internal-only cancelation code of either "Unpaid" or "Canceled".

"Unpaid" when the subscription has been canceled due to failure to collect payment by Stripe Billing's engine, or "Canceled" when you, the admin user, has manually marked the subscription as canceled.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you could add this as metadata against the subscription object. Metadata is available on most objects in Stripe with key/value pairs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-metadata